# how to style a prepend HTML hyperlink?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using an onclick function that interacts with JSON to extract a Hyperlink, title and description of wikipedia articles.

However I want to style each one of these on its own, by giving them unique ID/Class, I have giving  an ID but it wouldn't work.

```
for (var i=0; i<data[1].length;i++){

  $("#output").prepend("<li><a href= "+data[3][i]+"id = "styleme">"+data[1][i]+"</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
  }
```

Comment: Didn't you forget some '+' signs? `...+"id = " + styleme + ">"+...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the same id for each link: `id = "styleme"`. Also you need a space before id and replace double quotes with single for concatination: `'<li><a href= '+data[3][i]+' id = "styleme">'`

Comment: is it necessary to replace the double quotes with single ones?

Comment: I've tried this, I'm not sure if it's a single/double quotes issue or not, but it didn't work.
    `$("#output").prepend("<li><a href= " + data[3][i]+ " id="styleme"" + ">" +      data[1][i] +"</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");`

Comment: yes, necessary, and it didn't work because of quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = "data";
for (var i=0; i<data[1].length;i++){
$("#output").prepend("<li><a href= "+data[3][i]+"id = " + id + i + ">"+data[1][i]+"</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");}
```